# How to extract POST parameters in php

Tags: php, android, http-post, post-parameter

From android app, I am calling my php script.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.smth.net/some.php");
try {
// Add your data
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pa", "555"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pb", "550"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}
```

How do I get the value of "pa" and "pb" in my php script.

I did $_POST['pa'] and urldecode($_POST['pa']) but both of these give me empty string.

Comment: Have your tried using `print_r($_POST)` to see what's being sent?

Comment: @MarkOrmesher what would this do?

Comment: it would show everything that's being stored in `$_POST` - if it's empty, then you know that the problem is in the Android app.

Comment: @MarkOrmesher Yeah, it shows nothing. There was something wrong elsewhere. I'll delete this question. Or you can post this comment as answer, and I'll accept that.

Comment: Updated. Probably good to leave both code samples here for future visitors,  but your decision whether to accept either answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print_r($_POST)` to debug what is being sent.

If it helps, this is how I send info from Android using POST:

```
JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
requestBody.put("pa", "550");
requestBody.put("pb", "550");

HttpPost requestBase = new HttpPost("url");
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(requestBody.toString());
stringEntity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
requestBase.setEntity(stringEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(requestBase);
```

I'm working from memory here though - there are a couple of try/catches you'll need to insert.

Using a JSONObject might be unnecessary, but I found it gave me better flexibility and reliability.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `$_POST` environment variable. So, in your code, you can use  `$_POST["pa"]` and  `$_POST["pb"]`.

If this doesn't work, try using `var_dump` to check the contents of `$_POST` (`var_dump($_POST)`).  If it is empty, then it is a problem with your android code.

Comment: The OP already said that they've tried using `$_POST['pa']` and it didn't work.

Comment: @MarkOrmesher I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the content of `$_POST` array by using `extract()` function, The function reads all key-value pairs and creates variables with the key as name and the value as variable content. See the example below:

```
<form method="post" aciton="extract.php">
  <input type="text" name="foo" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<pre>
<?php
  function dump_extracted_post() {
    extract($_POST);
    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
  }
  dump_extracted_post();
?>
</pre>
```

Read more in [How to extract $_GET / $_POST parameters in PHP](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-extract-_get-_post-parameters-in-php/)